# How do I write an MVC Entity Framework select query from the controller using passed string arguments?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, viewdata

I created a search tool in MVC.  The user types the searchTerm string into a search box and selects options for the search from 2 dropdown select lists.  From the first list the user selects "Fuzzy" or "Literal" for the searchType, and from the second list the user can select a specific field to search, specField. The 3 string values are passed to the controller once the search button is clicked.
I am trying to write an "if" statement that queries the Entity Framework DB model based on these 3 string values passed into the controller.  How do I write queries that use these values?
This is what I have.  I know the queries aren't written correctly:

```
 Public PartialViewResult _Search(string searchTerm, string specField, string searchType)
 {
      //This works to populate the table with the entire DB 
      _db = new IntegrationDBEntities();
      var request = (from r in _db.Requests
                     select r).ToList();

     //These two are not correct and I need help writing these
     if (searchType == "Fuzzy" && searchTerm != "" && specField != "None")
     {
          request = (from r in _db.Requests
                          where r.(specField).Contains(searchTerm)
                          select r).ToList();
     }
     if (searchType == "Literal" && searchTerm != "" && specField == "None")
     {
          request = (from r in _db.Requests
                         where r.Equals(searchTerm)
                         select r).ToList();
     }
     ViewData.Model = request;
     Return partialView();
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not 100% sure about how you Request object looks like, but I would use [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx). Here is an example of what your search function could look like.

```
IQueryable<Request> SearchRequests (string searchTerm, string specField, string searchType)
{
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Request>();

    //These two are not correct and I need help writing these
    if (searchType == "Fuzzy" && searchTerm != "" && specField != "None")
    {
        predicate = predicate.Or (r => r.(specField).Contains(searchTerm));
    }
    if (searchType == "Literal" && searchTerm != "" && specField == "None")
    {
        predicate = predicate.Or (r => r.Equals(searchTerm));
    }

    return new IntegrationDBEntities()
                  .Requests
                  .AsExpandable()
                  .Where(predicate);
}
```

Then your method could look like this:

```
Public PartialViewResult _Search(string searchTerm, string specField, string searchType)
 {
     ViewData.Model = SearchRequests(searchTerm, specField, searchType).ToList();
     Return partialView();
 }
```

**UPDATE**: I added working example from LinqPad. You will need to modify it slightly to get it to work for you with `EntityFramework`.

```
void Main()
{
    var results = SearchRequests("Fuzzy", "later").ToList();
    results.Dump();

    var results2 = SearchRequests("Literal", "Test me now").ToList();
    results2.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Request
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string SearchTerm {get;set;}
}

public IQueryable<Request> LoadData()
{
    var list = new List<Request>();
    list.Add(new Request {Id = 1, SearchTerm = "Test me now"});
    list.Add(new Request {Id = 2, SearchTerm = "Test me later"});
    list.Add(new Request {Id = 3, SearchTerm = "Test me maybe"});
    list.Add(new Request {Id = 4, SearchTerm = "Test me now"});
    list.Add(new Request {Id = 5, SearchTerm = "Test me later or never"});
    list.Add(new Request {Id = 6, SearchTerm = "Test me maybe or today"});

    return list.AsQueryable();
}

public IQueryable<Request> SearchRequests (string searchType, string searchTerm)
{
    var data = LoadData();
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Request>();
    //These two are not correct and I need help writing these
    if (searchType == "Fuzzy")
    {
        predicate = predicate.Or(r => r.SearchTerm.Contains(searchTerm));
    }
    if (searchType == "Literal")
    {
        predicate = predicate.Or (r => r.SearchTerm.Equals(searchTerm));
    }

    return data.Where(predicate);
}

public static class PredicateBuilder
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T> ()  { return f => true;  }
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T> () { return f => false; }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T> (this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                        Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke (expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression> ());
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
            (Expression.OrElse (expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T> (this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                        Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke (expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression> ());
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
            (Expression.AndAlso (expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
    }
}
```

Results for first search:

```
Id  SearchTerm
2   Test me later
5   Test me later or never
```

Results for second search:

```
Id  SearchTerm
1   Test me now
4   Test me now
```

Comment: The " predicate = predicate.Or(..." Parts are gving me an error.  Also, ".AsExpandable()" is as well.

Comment: @antman1p I updated the answer with working LinqPad example. AsExpandable() is needed for EntityFramework, but since I am not using EntityFramework in the example, I cannot validate that part. PredicateBuilder is solid in my opinion. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @CmaStena  i just read that I will need to download the LinqKit.dll

Comment: @antman1p is that acceptable approach for you? Yes, AsExpandable() is part of that .DLL.

Comment: Yes, it is just a bit of a pain.  I work in a "different" environment.  I'll get it to the dev system and try it out.

Comment: OK, so I referenced Linqkit.  AsExpandable works now.  I am still gettting errors on the predicate = predicate.Or (... lines and the .Where(predicate);  line.  ".... cannot be inf3erred from usage.  try specifying the type arguments explicitly."

Comment: Now, the only thing that I cannot get to work is:  predicate = predicate.Or (r=> r.specField.Contains (searchTerm);  The problem is the searchTerm is a variable that represents the field of the table that the user wants to search in for the term the user typed.  How do I get this to allow me to use that variable?

Comment: @antman1p can you post what your Request class definition looks like? I am not sure I understand what you need to search over? Are you searching over specField if one is selected from the UI? And if specField is not specified, then what are you searching over?

Comment: I got it to work by adding a switch case.  Thanks you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works with no errors:

```
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Request), "Request");
Expression property = Expression.Property(pe, specField);
Expression predicate = null;
Expression srch = Expression.Constant(searchTerm, typeof(string));
if(searchType == "Fuzzy")
{
    MethodInfo contains = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
    predicate = Expression.Call(property, contains, srch);
}
else
{
    predicate = Expression.Equal(property, srch);
}

MethodCallExpression where = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Queryable),
    "Where",
    new Type[] { _db.Requests.ElementType },
    _db.Requests.Expression,
    Expression.Lambda<Func<Request, bool>>(predicate, new ParameterExpression[] { pe }));

IQueryable<Request> result = _db.Requests.Provider.CreateQuery<Request>(where);

var list = result.ToList();
```

Let me know if you have any trouble

Comment: Why have you fully qualified all of your types?

Comment: I'm getting a Error "Best Overloaded method...." for :  Epression containsFoo = Expression.Call(property, contains, searchTerm);

Comment: I made a mistake. Third argument must be also an Expression. Check line 4 and 8 for updates :)

Comment: in the MethodCallExpression new Type[] { _db.Requests.ElementType } at 'ElementType"  ...Models.request>does not contain a definition for 'ElementType'...

Comment: Sorry, was writing by heart. Should be _db.Requests.AsQueryable().ElementType. Or just typeof(Request). It represents the underlying type for Queryable you want to filter  via MethodCallExpression.